# why approval index action not redirect to pending action view although no error on debug code?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, c#-7.3

I work on an ASP.NET MVC project. I face issue action `ApprovalIndex` is not redirecting to action `PendingManagersRequests` although no error happens.

I debug and trace breakpoint until reach action `PendingManagersRequests` and trace until I reach to view `return View(vmr);` without any issues.

So why is it not redirected to the view `PendingManagersRequests` although no issues happen?

My code: when click button approve submit, it updates a table column `SpeakStuffComment` based on `RequestNo`:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("ApprovalIndex", "Resignation", new { id = Model.RequestNo }, FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @style = "display:inline;" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        
    <a onclick="submit();" class="btn btn-primary" style="min-width: 100px;
            margin-left: 5px;">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Approve 
    </a>
}
```

When click approve button, it calls `ApprovalIndex` on controller `ResignationController`:

```
public class ResignationController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ApprovalIndex(ResignationRequester REQ)
    {
        string errorMsg = string.Empty;
        string requestStatus;

        Workforce.ResignationUpdateLineManangerApproval(id, true,Convert.ToInt32(Session[SessionKeys.UserCode]));

        return RedirectToAction("PendingManagersRequests", new { msg = $"Request NO {REQ.RequestNo} has been accepted " +
                        $"successfully." });
    }
}
```

jQuery calls action `approvalIndex` on `resignation` controller:

```
    function submit() {
        var ResignationRequester = new Object();
        ResignationRequester.RequestNo = document.getElementById("RequestNo").innerHTML.trim();
        ResignationRequester.EmpID = document.getElementById("EmpID").innerHTML.trim();
        ResignationRequester.SpeakStuffComment = document.getElementById("SpeakStuffComment").value;

        if (ResignationRequester != null) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("ApprovalIndex", "Resignation")',
                data: JSON.stringify(ResignationRequester),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>

public async Task<ActionResult> PendingManagersRequests(string msg, string errorMsg)
{
    ViewModelRequests vmr = new ViewModelRequests();
      
    vmr.MyRequests = Workforce.GetPendingToDisplayMyRequests(Session[SessionKeys.UserCode].ToString());

    ViewBag.msg = msg;
    ViewBag.errorMsg = errorMsg;

    return View(vmr);
}
```

Finally I get only this popup localhost say although from action `approvalindex` no error

[image: error local host say]

Comment: When you turn on developer tools in your browser and look at the network requests, does the call to `ApprovalIndex` return a redirect status result or a 200 status result?

Comment: can you show to me how  to see dev tools request and how to see it is 200 ok or not can you show me please

Comment: can you help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirects don't work when you call the server via ajax.

You have to "redirect" (it's not really a redirect) client side:

```
    if (ResignationRequester != null) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("ApprovalIndex", "Resignation")',
            data: JSON.stringify(ResignationRequester),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                window.location = "/Home/PendingManagersRequests?msg=something";
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```